# is possible connect the xbox360 controller to ubuntu without reciver?

Tags: video-player, joystick, xbox-360

i have a question: i have a one controll of PS4 and i connecte it with my laptop ubuntu and it work fine, but i have a cousin and the have a xbox console with two xbox controlls, we try connect them with my PC and we can't do it :'( we search in the web and we find something called "xboxdrv" and others file configs, but nothing work :/

it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Answer:***

No, you cannot.

***Explanation:***

The XBox 360 Controller runs on a proprietary 2.4 GHz protocol.  While the Wii and PS3/4 Controllers run on Bluetooth.

There is no way to connect the XBox 360 Controllers to a PC without the use of either a USB cable or the Wireless Gaming Receiver.

***Further Reading:***

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_360_accessories#Wireless_Gaming_Receiver

Comment: @SonickSeven - You're welcome :)